# Possible Broken Shifter

Tags: repair, shimano, shifter

My right Shimano shifter is now loose and clicking it doesn't do anything to the rear derailleur. I've checked the derailleur and it still works fine. How can I fix the shifter?

Edit: It's a road bike cable shifter; it has the brakes with it as well so it's a brifter (?). I have potentially found the problem. Something in the cable seems to have snapped as the cable has come out of the shifter. Any way to fix that?

Edit 2: I realised that someone shared a link on how to replace the cable in the comments so this question has been answered. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Short answer is probably not. The internals of shifters are famous for going 'ping' in all directions if you open them. It is possible but will be a PITA to put back together and you may not be able to fix it anyway. When I asked my LBS they said parts for (lower end) shifters aren't sold.

Comment: Check that you have enough cable tension (if you hold the shift cable taut, you should feel the shifter pulling/loosening the cable when you click it). Generally, shifters are not repairable parts (even on the high end), so you'll need to get a new compatible shifter if the end diagnosis is that you need a new shifter.

Comment: What kind of shifter is it?  Mountain / road?  Electric or cable operated?  Is it a combination brake lever gear shifter (brifter) or a standalone shifter?  Shimano has made hundreds of shifters over the years.  I understand if you don't know exactly what kind of shifter it is, but try to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Check the cable.  If it is bad for sure you need to replace the cable even if you also need to replace the shifter.  http://ccorlew.blogspot.com/p/shimano-ultegra-shifter-cable-frayed.html

Comment: What do you mean by loose?

Comment: A recent post here discussed Grease in Shimano Brifters drying out so they would not latch - is this the possible cause ("loose" is a "loose" term to describe the problem, and you don't say what kind of shifters you have)

Comment: I had the same problem with an old Shimano Alivio "RapidFire" MTB shifter.  The solution was to replace the shifter, which cost all of $20.

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question, please post it as an answer rather than editing it into your question. Answering your own question is an [acceptable and even encouraged practice](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the edit, put a new cable on. And while you're at it, you may as well replace the cable housing.